# Error in exists("meta", envir = ui) : invalid 'envir' argument

Tags: r

I am trying to obtain AUC and Cmax on nlmxir2

This is my code:

```
FinalModel <- function() {
       ini({
    
       tcl <- log(2.96) # typical value of clearance
       tv <- log(37.1) # typical value of volume
    
       eta.cl ~ 0.1 # interindividual variability on clearance 
       eta.v ~ 0.1 # interindividual variability on volume
    
    
      add.err <- 10 # residual variability
    
   })
   model({
      ka <- 1.5 # individual value of ka (fixed)
      cl <- exp(tcl + eta.cl + 0.75*logwt)*(1 + 0.0614 * TDAYS) # allometric scaling on weight, % increase in favipiravir CL/F per day on CL
    v <- exp(tv  + eta.v + 1*logwt)  # allometric scaling on weight
    ke <- cl / v # elimination rate constant
    d/dt(A1) = -ka * A1 # dose compartment 
    d/dt(A2) = ka * A1 - ke * A2 # central compartment
    cp = A2 / v # concentration in plasma
    d/dt(auc) <- cp
    cp ~ add(add.err) # define error model
    
  })
}

e<- et(amt=200, ii=6, until=24) %>% 
   et(0,24, length.out=24)

   
s<-rxSolve(FinalModel,e)
```

When I try to calculate s, I get: Error in exists("meta", envir = ui) : invalid 'envir' argument

I don't know how to fix that error, would you please assist me?